# Event Scheduling Greedy

Tags: algorithm, greedy

We are given N ranges of date offsets when N employees are present in an
organization. Something like 
1-4 (i.e. employee will come on 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th day )
2-6
8-9
..
1-14
We have to organize an event on minimum number of days such that each
employee can attend the event at least twice.Please suggest the algorithm(probably greedy) to do this.
PS: Event is one day event.

Comment: Does the event need to happen at consecutive days?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is small, you can just brute-force it.  Pick all possible combination of 2 days.  For each combination, try it and see if everyone can attend both.  If not, pick all possible combinations of 3 days, see if everyone can attend 2 out of the 3, and so on.  It's exponential, but may not be so bad for your purposes.

The greedy approach is to count how many people are at work each day, and pick the day with the maximum number of people.  Repeating, count how many people are at work each day *who don't already have two events scheduled* and pick the day with the maximum number of people.  Of course, don't pick the same day twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by the following greedy approach on events sorted with end date

```
Maintain a num count for all intervals. (Initialize all to 0)
If num = 0 place the two events on the last two days of this interval. 
If num = 1 place one event on the last day of this interval
If num = 2 already two events have been covered for this interval.
```

Placing on the event in an interval can lead to increase in num count of the succeeding event.